# UITableView duplicated cell in last section

Tags: swift

I have a table view with 3 sections.
In the last section I have two cells.
No when I click on the last cell (Segue to a ViewController) and come back to the tableView my last cell is exactly the same with the previous cell(section 2 row 0). When I close the app and come back to the tableView everything is OK.
I've searched a lot but found nothing about this.

Here is my code:

```
else if indexPath.section == 2 {

        let cell2:SecondTwoWayCellTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondTwoWayCell") as!SecondTwoWayCellTableViewCell



                if indexPath.row == 0 && DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[4] != "" {



                    let currentPlayerHome1 = CoreDataManager.defaultListener().getPlayer(date, identifier: DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[4]) as! Player
                    let currentPlayerHome2 = CoreDataManager.defaultListener().getPlayer(date, identifier: DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[5]) as! Player

                    let currentPlayerAway1 = CoreDataManager.defaultListener().getPlayer(date, identifier: DoubleMatchIdentifierAway[4]) as! Player
                    let currentPlayerAway2 = CoreDataManager.defaultListener().getPlayer(date, identifier: DoubleMatchIdentifierAway[5]) as! Player


                    cell2.identifierPlayerHome1.text     = DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[4]
                    cell2.playerHome1.text               = currentPlayerHome1.name!
                    cell2.identifierPlayerHome2.text     = DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[5]
                    cell2.playerHome2.text               = currentPlayerHome2.name!

                    cell2.identifierPlayerAway1.text     = DoubleMatchIdentifierAway[4]
                    cell2.playerAway1.text               = currentPlayerAway1.name!
                    cell2.identifierPlayerAway2.text     = DoubleMatchIdentifierAway[5]
                    cell2.playerAway2.text               = currentPlayerAway2.name!

                    cell2.score.text         = ("\(matches[18].scoreHome!):\(matches[18].scoreAway!)")

                     return cell2
            }

            else if indexPath.row == 1 && DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[6] != "" {




                    let currentPlayerHome1 = CoreDataManager.defaultListener().getPlayer(date, identifier: DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[6]) as! Player
                    let currentPlayerHome2 = CoreDataManager.defaultListener().getPlayer(date, identifier: DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[7]) as! Player

                    let currentPlayerAway1 = CoreDataManager.defaultListener().getPlayer(date, identifier: DoubleMatchIdentifierAway[6]) as! Player
                    let currentPlayerAway2 = CoreDataManager.defaultListener().getPlayer(date, identifier: DoubleMatchIdentifierAway[7]) as! Player




                    cell2.identifierPlayerHome1.text     = DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[6]
                    cell2.playerHome1.text               = currentPlayerHome1.name!
                    cell2.identifierPlayerHome2.text     = DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[7]
                    cell2.playerHome2.text               = currentPlayerHome2.name!

                    cell2.identifierPlayerAway1.text     = DoubleMatchIdentifierAway[6]
                    cell2.playerAway1.text               = currentPlayerAway1.name!
                    cell2.identifierPlayerAway2.text     = DoubleMatchIdentifierAway[7]
                    cell2.playerAway2.text               = currentPlayerAway2.name!

                    cell2.score.text         = ("\(matches[19].scoreHome!):\(matches[19].scoreAway!)")

                     return cell2

            }

       return cell2






    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you unwrap the cell at the begining of the code by putting:

let cell2:SecondTwoWayCellTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondTwoWayCell") as!SecondTwoWayCellTableViewCell

the you do an if to check things... but you dont clean the cell and remember that you are reusing a cell with identifier...
So, what you need to do is just to clear the cell after you deque the cell by putting something like:

cell2 = SecondTwoWayCellTableViewCell()

and then the "if indexPath.row == 0 && DoubleMatchIdentifierHome[4] != "" {"

so the cell always goes to standard values in case it does not fall in any if.

Comment: If I put cell2 = SecondTwoWayCellTableViewCell() after the dequeue i will get a blank cell :(

Comment: Now it works, but i dont know why :) I wrote 
              cell2 = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SecondTwoWayCell") as! SecondTwoWayCellTableViewCell after the var cell2 = ..... and finally it works. Does anybody know why? I have the same code for section 0 and it works without the addition!